# Integrating two models into a single model ( Object classification and Gender classification & emotion recognition)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda

I have been dealing with a project on ML in which we are willing to build an offline application. So we are not using the API's for this project, instead we two models. One for Object classification and the other for Gender classification & emotion recognition. Now I have problem with integrating the two models into one. Both the models are in OpenCV.

> > Code for deep_learning_object_detecti*on
>
> ```
> # USAGE
> # python deep_learning_object_detection.py --image images/example_01.jpg \
> #--prototxt MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt --model MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel
>
> # import the necessary packages
> import numpy as np
> import argparse
> import cv2  
>
> # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
> ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
>   help="path to input image")
> ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
>   help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
> ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
>   help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
> ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2,
>   help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
> args = vars(ap.parse_args())
>
> # initialize the list of class labels MobileNet SSD was trained to
> # detect, then generate a set of bounding box colors for each class
> CLASSES = ["background", "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat",
>   "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable",
>   "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep",
>   "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]
> COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(CLASSES), 3))
>
> # load our serialized model from disk
> print("[INFO] loading model...")
> net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])
>
> # load the input image and construct an input blob for the image
> # by resizing to a fixed 300x300 pixels and then normalizing it
> # (note: normalization is done via the authors of the MobileNet SSD
> # implementation)
> image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
> (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
> blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)
>
> # pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
> # predictions
> print("[INFO] computing object detections...")
> net.setInput(blob)
> detections = net.forward()
>
> # loop over the detections
> for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
>   # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
>   # prediction
>   confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
>
>   # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
>   # greater than the minimum confidence
>   if confidence > args["confidence"]:
>       # extract the index of the class label from the `detections`,
>       # then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
>       # the object
>       idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
>       box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
>       (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
>
>       # display the prediction
>       label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx], confidence * 100)
>       print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
>       cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
>           COLORS[idx], 2)
>       y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
>       cv2.putText(image, label, (startX, y),
>           cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)
>
> # show the output image
>
> cv2.imshow("Output", image)
> cv2.waitKey(0)
> ```
>
> Code for Gender and emotion recognition
>
> ```
> import sys
> import argparse
> import cv2
> from keras.models import load_model
> import numpy as np
>
> from utils.datasets import get_labels
> from utils.inference import detect_faces
> from utils.inference import draw_text
> from utils.inference import draw_bounding_box
> from utils.inference import apply_offsets
> from utils.inference import load_detection_model
> from utils.inference import load_image
> from utils.preprocessor import preprocess_input
>
> # parameters for loading data and images
> image_path = sys.argv[1]
> detection_model_path = '../trained_models/detection_models/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
> emotion_model_path = '../trained_models/emotion_models/fer2013_mini_XCEPTION.102-0.66.hdf5'
> gender_model_path = '../trained_models/gender_models/simple_CNN.81-0.96.hdf5'
> emotion_labels = get_labels('fer2013')
> gender_labels = get_labels('imdb')
> font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
>
> # hyper-parameters for bounding boxes shape
> gender_offsets = (30, 60)
> gender_offsets = (10, 10)
> emotion_offsets = (20, 40)
> emotion_offsets = (0, 0)
>
> # loading models
> face_detection = load_detection_model(detection_model_path)
> emotion_classifier = load_model(emotion_model_path, compile=False)
> gender_classifier = load_model(gender_model_path, compile=False)
>
> # getting input model shapes for inference
> emotion_target_size = emotion_classifier.input_shape[1:3]
> gender_target_size = gender_classifier.input_shape[1:3]
>
> # loading images
> rgb_image = load_image(image_path, grayscale=False)
> gray_image = load_image(image_path, grayscale=True)
> gray_image = np.squeeze(gray_image)
> gray_image = gray_image.astype('uint8')
>
> faces = detect_faces(face_detection, gray_image)
> for face_coordinates in faces:
>     x1, x2, y1, y2 = apply_offsets(face_coordinates, gender_offsets)
>     rgb_face = rgb_image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
>
>     x1, x2, y1, y2 = apply_offsets(face_coordinates, emotion_offsets)
>     gray_face = gray_image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
>
>     try:
>         rgb_face = cv2.resize(rgb_face, (gender_target_size))
>         gray_face = cv2.resize(gray_face, (emotion_target_size))
>     except:
>         continue
>
>     rgb_face = preprocess_input(rgb_face, False)
>     rgb_face = np.expand_dims(rgb_face, 0)
>     gender_prediction = gender_classifier.predict(rgb_face)
>     gender_label_arg = np.argmax(gender_prediction)
>     gender_text = gender_labels[gender_label_arg]
>
>     gray_face = preprocess_input(gray_face, True)
>     gray_face = np.expand_dims(gray_face, 0)
>     gray_face = np.expand_dims(gray_face, -1)
>     emotion_label_arg = np.argmax(emotion_classifier.predict(gray_face))
>     emotion_text = emotion_labels[emotion_label_arg]
>
>     if gender_text == gender_labels[0]:
>         color = (0, 0, 255)
>     else:
>         color = (255, 0, 0)
>
>     draw_bounding_box(face_coordinates, rgb_image, color)
>     draw_text(face_coordinates, rgb_image, gender_text, color, 0, -20, 1, 2)
>     draw_text(face_coordinates, rgb_image, emotion_text, color, 0, -50, 1, 2)
>
> bgr_image = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
> cv2.imwrite('../images/predicted_test_image.png', bgr_image)
> ```

How to integrate these two models into a single model.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can't you do one after the other?

Comment: I want to build an application with a single model and that's the requirement too.

Comment: How the general object detection network which has such classes as tvmonitor and cow can be applied to gender recognition pipeline?